# MySQL sql as column

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I've got the following table

```
db.queries
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name      | varchar(256)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| sql       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| frequency | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 86400   |                |
```

I am inserting values which are as labeled, a **name** and a **sql query** like so using the MySQLdb python tool.

```
cur.execute("insert into db.queries (name, sql, frequency) values ('{0}', '{1}', {2})".format('some query', 'Select a query', 86400)
```

I've used MySQL and MySQLdb many times before and never have had these issues.

The error I'm constantly getting is as follows:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sql, frequency) values ('MY NAME', 'Select  count(*) as' at line 1")

I appreciate any help.

Comment: There's a facility for storing queries in the database: [Stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html). Storing SQL in a database is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

`sql` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, you need to put it in backticks:

```
cur.execute("insert into db.queries (name, `sql`, frequency) values ('{0}', '{1}', {2})".format('some query', 'Select a query', 86400)
```

Comment: While I guessed immediately that that was the problem, I had no recollection until I read the error message that SQL was a reserved word. Why is it reserved?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's used in triggers or stored functions?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed it was a reserved word right after posting this, but I didn't know that I could still use it with the backticks.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

`sql` is a reserved word in MySQL.  Put it in backticks, like so:

```
cur.execute("insert into db.queries (name, `sql`, frequency) values ('{0}', '{1}', {2})".format('some query', 'Select a query', 86400)
```